# Clearing the Screen in C on Solaris, Linux, Windows and Mac

Tags: c, macos

I am writing a small application in C and want to clear the terminal/dos window of text.

So far I have:

```
  if (system("cls"))
    system("clear");
```

Which seems to work fine on just about everything except Mac, which gives me the error:

> sh: cls: command not found TERM
>   environment variable not set.

Whats weird, is that `clear` from the terminal works, but not `system(clear);` and I am not sure why.

Does anyone know how I can stop this, or modify my code to clear the screen on a Mac terminal which will work on other ANSI C compliant compilers, without, obviously, writing a bunch of '/n's to the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear the console in BOTH Windows and Linux using C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228617/how-do-i-clear-the-console-in-both-windows-and-linux-using-c)

Comment: What if some user wants to pipe to/from your small application? `cat somefile | yourApp | grep foobar` ??? Can you do without clearing the screen?

Comment: Well, since I am learning C, I am more concerned with learning how to clear it, than whether or not a user wants to pipe to/from my application! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with compiling and running inside XCode.  When compiled and run outside XCode, the code works as expected. Doh!