# GNU/Linux replacements for Turbo C functions `clrscr` and `cprintf`

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ncurses, bgi

I just moved to Linux for just a month. I've used Borland Turbo C for C programming but some of these functions do not work in GNU/Linux, so looking for help.

These are some of the functions I would like to replace:
 - gotoxy
 - cprintf
 - clrscr
 - initgraph/graphics.h

I would appreciate some code examples showing how to use any replacements.

Comment: Also, that's an ancient compiler.  There are a lot of modern alternatives that are better and more standards-compliant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In linux, you can use the ncurses library to use the terminal as a text buffer: move the cursor around, and write text. It can also draw windows and other hi-level widgets.

For `gotoxy` see `move` and `wmove` from ncurses ([link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wmove)).
For `cprintf` see `printw`.
You can clear the screen simply with `clear()`.

In ncurses you also need to refresh the screen with `refresh()` after `printw` and `clear()`.

Example program, which uses all the mentioned functions in ncurses:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    clear();
    move(15, 20);
    printw("Test program: %s", argv[0]);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile in gcc with: `gcc program.c -lcurses`

As for graphics, you have to choose a particular library.
If you need a similar experience as the low-level graphics.h, you are probably looking for [directfb](http://directfb.org/) or [svgalib](http://www.svgalib.org/).
If you want to render graphics in a window, [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) will be helpful.

Comment: a little code will be appreciated for **clrscr** and **cprintf**

Comment: I edited the answer with ncurses versions of `clrscr`, `cprintf` and `gotoxy`.

Answer (score 5):

The functions you refer to are part of Borland's proprietary library for console applications. You want to read about [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/).

Comment: a little code will be appreciated for **clrscr** and **cprintf** !

Answer (score 0):

**About graphics.h**

Regarding using graphics.h in Linux is an easy task. I had the same problem a week ago. Well you can goggle with search term "graphics.h in Linux", and you will get many links and here is one.

http://www.rajivnair.in/2007/07/graphicsh-in-gnulinux.html.

**About Clear Screen**

For that, you have many options.
And the one is,
using system("clear") but it needs stdlib.h and it is slower in performance.
Here two links for you...

[How do I clear the console in BOTH Windows and Linux using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228617/how-do-i-clear-the-console-in-both-windows-and-linux-using-c)

[cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/faq/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1031963460&id=1043284385)

**About gotoxy**
 As mentioned in Michał Trybus's Answer.

**About cprintf**

I Referred many links, but not getting the simple answers. Me too waiting for the answers for this.
  But,In my experience whenever I want the output to be in some colored format , I will use graphics.h, though it is not required.That's why I doesn't had this question in my mind ever before.
You may find this link useful...
[codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-425659.html)

**About getch**
  I think you may already know about this. Instead of getch() in conio.h(not in ansi standard),  you can use getchar() in stdio.h.

Answer (score 0):

Just, I was answering the same questions in another thread:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
  printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B, y, x);
}

void clrscr(void) {
  fprintf(stdout, "\033[2J\033[0;0f");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void textcolor(int attr, int fg, int bg) {   
  printf("%c[%d;%d;%dm", 0x1B, attr, fg + 30, bg + 40);
}
```

Easy way to do it!