# how to execute a statement every 3 iteration of loop?

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

The language is C++ and I am trying to use **system("cls")** in a **do{} while** loop, but I don't want it to run this statement the first time or the second. I want this statement to run the 3rd time. is there any way to run this code inside a do-while loop after every 3 iteration of the loop?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of `system("cls");`, I'd use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7911218/179910). Much faster, and about the same degree of portability (i.e., none in either case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `i%3` as others have suggested, I'd avoid the (usually fairly slow) division operation and just reset the counter when it fires:

```
int i=0;
do { 
   if (++i == 3) {
       clear_screen();
       i = 0;
   }
} while (whatever());
```

Granted, when you're clearing the screen (especially via a `system` call) it's so slow the difference from avoiding division is a drop of water in the ocean, but cultivating good habits is a good thing, and in this case you gain speed with no loss of readability, so it's clearly a net gain.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
do
{
  i++;
  if(!(i % 3))
    system("cls");
}while(True)
```

Comment: There is no reason to increase and check separately - `if( !( ++i % 3 ) )` IMHO more readable or even `if( ++i % 3 == 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a counter and provide an if conditon like as follows :-

```
int c=0;
do{
   c++
   ....
   ....
   if (c%3==0)
     system("cls");
   ...
   ...
  }while();
```

adjust this code as desired   :-)