# I created a program in c which print out a statement , then after some second it clear and replace with a new printed statement

Tags: c

The program is interactive.... But after putting scanf it cannot clear the first statement, anyone knows the solution

```
char firstn[100];
char secondn[100];
printf("\n\bPlease Enter Your First Name:  ");
scanf("%s", &firstn );
fflush(stdout);
Sleep(1234);
printf("\r\bPlease Enter Your Second Name: ");
scanf("%s", &Secondn);
```

Comment: What is the return value of your scanf calls? And what does that mean according to scanf documentation?

Comment: char is good for storing 1 character like 'a'. For C-strings you need and array of char: `char firstn[100];` and you read it using `scanf("%99s", firstn)`

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot clear the first statement"?

Comment: What does scanf documentation say about the paramters after the format string? Does it need the value of a suitable variable, or somethign else?

Comment: The scanf stores what I type in has my name

Comment: When dealing with scanf() be sure to first study the extremely helpful http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: I assume he means removing the first printed line. @Yunnosch, which I answered.

Comment: @Annabelle A bold guess indeed.

Comment: You did not post the actual code you have a problem with. Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the screen you can use:

```
... // Other headers
#include <stdlib.h>

int main{
   ... // Code
   system("clear"); // or system("cls"); on Windows.
   ... // Code
}
```

And this should work for your purposes.

If you need to clear a specific line only, [you can use ncurses as this Q&A demonstrates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072881/how-to-clear-a-specific-line-with-ncurses)

Comment: Nice code bro.... Is there a way to limit the point of Line at which system must clear

Comment: Or any other OS where clear isn't a command that can be run independently.  There is no prtable way to clear the screen.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154579/how-do-i-clear-the-screen-in-c

Comment: @AlarmedDino My comment with `system("cls");` should work fine.

Comment: @jmt See my extra note.

Comment: Ohh thanks allot... Can we be friends on Facebook @Annabelle